# Working with IME names in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, ime

Delphi TScreen object has a collection that accepts IME names.  And the TControl offers SetIMEName method.

Are these IME names constant?  Are they same as ISO language names?

Platform: Windows XP.

Thanks, 
Pavan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not ISO language names. They are names of keyboard layouts. Look at the implementation of `TScreen.GetImes` in *Forms.pas* to see that the list comes from reading the *layout text* key values from the *HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layouts* registry keys.

Some values from my computer that make it obvious it's not a list of language names include *Latin American*, *United Kingdom Extended*, *Chinese (Simplified) - US Keyboard*, *Divehi Phonetic*, *Lithuanian IBM*, and *Russian (Typewriter)*.